# use the python matplotlib to draw scatter with band distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, scatter-plot, normal-distribution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdZTf.png)
How to use python matplotlib to plor such beautiful 2-D scatter like the picture A，I try my best but only draw picture like B

I wish I can figure out the band distribution images in picture A whether were made in photoshop or Ai. If I use python matplotlib, can I draw this picture without post-processing?

Comment: See https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/hexbin_marginals.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want a ready-to-use solution you can achieve similar results using the `jointplot` function of the `seaborn` library: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html.

Note that this is just a `matplotlib` wrapper that simplifies some of the definitions; you could achieve exactly the same with `matplotlib` alone by drawing the different plots (in your case a combination of 1 heatmap and 2 marginal distributions) on 3 axes and then sticking them together on the same figure.

There are many resources in the matplotlib wiki on how to achieve this.